# BiosInitTime from Hibernate Resume ETW trace

Tags: bios, etw, xperf

Looking at the "BiosInitTime" from ETW events parsed using "tracerpt.exe" and I noticed for hibernate/S4 resume it's always 0 (see example at the end). The same happened with etl traces collected directly using XPERF or via ADK Windows Assessment Console. But via WAC/WPA analysis & GUI, the BIOS will be shown. So it appears the information is there but "tracerpt.exe" is parsing the wrong events to calculate "BiosInitTime".

What specific start/stop events I should check to calculate the Bios Init Time via etl trace, say, using xperf?

Thanks

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
    <EventID>39</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>33</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x400000000000000C</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-02-03T15:08:43.601479000Z" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="3140" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="180" UserTime="0" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power/Diagnostic</Channel>
    <Computer />
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data Name="SleepTime">    1546</Data>
    <Data Name="ResumeTime">     769</Data>
    <Data Name="DriverWakeTime">     715</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberWriteTime">    2999</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberReadTime">    1862</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberPagesWritten">  148964</Data>
    **<Data Name="BiosInitTime">       0</Data>**
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
    <Level>Information </Level>
    <Opcode>Info </Opcode>
    <Keywords>
        <Keyword>po:Diagnostic</Keyword>
        <Keyword>po:Performance</Keyword>
    </Keywords>
    <Task>PowerTransition</Task>
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power/Diagnostic</Channel>
    <Provider>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power </Provider>
</RenderingInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power` events are not captured into the ETL when selecting hibernation in WPRUI.exe. You can see this if you open the ETL with [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) and look in the raw event list.

So when you try to search for the `BiosInitTime` it shows as 0. If you can see if when running the ADK Windows Assessment Console, this means here the `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power` events are captured.

Comment: The sample output is from ADK. ADK definitely tracks `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power` and Bios time is shown via the GUI and in the auto-parsed result file, in different fields defined by the WPA profile. But that `BiosInitTime` event directly from `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power` is always 0ms.

Comment: can you share a trace captured via the ADK? I never tried this